# AngularJS: Trying to create a dynamic dropdown

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a dynamic dropdown of this year and the next 3 years that will update automatically as the year changes. I am getting an unexpected token error from this attempt:

CONTROLLER:

```
$scope.thisYear = new Date().getFullYear();
$scope.year_span = [
   {'id'=>$scope.thisYear, 'year'=>$scope.thisYear},
   {'id'=>$scope.thisYear+1, 'year'=>$scope.thisYear+1},
   {'id'=>$scope.thisYear+2, 'year'=>$scope.thisYear+2},
   {'id'=>$scope.thisYear+3, 'year'=>$scope.thisYear+3}
];
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label>Crop Year:</label>
    <select name="crop_year" ng-model="frmData.loan.crop_year" class="form-control" ng-options="ys.id as ys.year for ys in year_span">
        <option value="">Please select ...</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it should be

```
$scope.year_span = [
{'id': $scope.thisYear, 'year':$scope.thisYear},
{'id': $scope.thisYear+1, 'year':$scope.thisYear+1},
{'id': $scope.thisYear+2, 'year':$scope.thisYear+2},
{'id': $scope.thisYear+3, 'year':$scope.thisYear+3}
];
```

as the correct syntax for object is `{key:value}`

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.year_span = [
       {'id'=>$scope.thisYear, 'year'=>$scope.thisYear},
       {'id'=>$scope.thisYear+1, 'year'=>$scope.thisYear+1},
       {'id'=>$scope.thisYear+2, 'year'=>$scope.thisYear+2},
       {'id'=>$scope.thisYear+3, 'year'=>$scope.thisYear+3}
    ];
```

In the above code, you are creating javascript objects inside an array. In javascript, objects are key value pairs and the correct syntax to do it is

```
{ key: value}
```

In your example, you have written

```
{ key => value }
```

This is the array syntax in PHP, so I think you have mixed the syntax

If you just change your declaration as below, things will work.

```
$scope.year_span = [
{'id': $scope.thisYear, 'year':$scope.thisYear},
{'id': $scope.thisYear+1, 'year':$scope.thisYear+1},
{'id': $scope.thisYear+2, 'year':$scope.thisYear+2},
{'id': $scope.thisYear+3, 'year':$scope.thisYear+3}
];
```